# Outlook 2010 intermittently going offline

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Just a quick question to see if anyone can give me any direction in or solve the the following problem:

Within the office there are a minority who use Outlook client using IMAP: Dovecot  and the rest use Thunderbird on Linux also using IMAP: Dovecot  via the same mail server. The people who are using Outlook 2010 are repeated (almost daily) reporting outages of emailing services for hours at a time forcing them to sign in and out etc but the people using Thunderbird do not have any issues what so ever which I assume will rule out an issue with the old mail server we are currently using.

Any help in the matter would be hugely appreciated and of course if I can provide any further information to articulate understanding of the issue then please just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: @DaveRook yeah that is absolutely the case.

Comment: I suggest first seeing if the same issue persists if Outlook is run in safemode to rule out any plugins or conflicts. I would also check to make sure that it is using the same ports/security etc

Comment: Thanks @DaveRook I heard there is some sort of Outlook Diagnostic Tool that may be of help. Would you recommend that and how would I access it?

Comment: I have looked online. The material suggest that the tool resided in Programs > Microsoft > Microsoft Office Tools but I only have a folder named Microsoft Office 2010 Tools which does not contain the Microsoft Office Diagnostics program. Thanks I appreciate it.

Comment: Check office diagnostic tool in outlook under help. If you don’t see the option, try to repair office 2010 from control panel-> programs and features. Or, run diagnostics from the CD

Comment: Ok I am in the process of setting up a fresh Windows 7 platform with Outlook and will action all of your suggestions. The link you provided is for 2007 and is completely different in 2010 but like I said I will search it in help.

Comment: There is no 2010 option to do this (sorry I didn't read the 2010 bit of your post, my fault!). http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_other/how-to-run-diagnostics-tool-in-office-2010/dfdfe0a2-7f5e-4882-beef-89abbeb77942